# How do I get rid of this green bar beside the line numbers in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, editor

[Image of Green Bar that is bothering me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYBMF.png)

I there is a green bar beside the numbers that I just can't seem to get rid of when I click on it it says one on one change and it apples on every line that I edit. I am not really sure how this works.

Comment: Those are your source control diff decorations, see the setting `SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Visibility` and similar settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Vscode extension. I'd suggest disabling each extension, one by one, and then observing if the behaviour continues.

Comment: have you worked with VSC, the comment by Mark is correct